# powershell - list local users and their groups

Tags: powershell, user-accounts

I'd like to have a report with all the local users and their relative groups (users, power users, administrators and so on.

I get the users in this way:

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://."
$adsi.psbase.children | where {$_.psbase.schemaClassName -match "user"} | select @{n="Name";e={$_.name}}
```

but I don't know how to retrieve their groups. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | Foreach-Object {
    $groups = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
    $_ | Select-Object @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}},@{n='Groups';e={$groups -join ';'}}
}
```

Answer (score 41):

For Googlers, another way to get a list of users is to use:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount
```

From http://buckeyejeeps.com/blog/?p=764

Comment: You want to add the filter to that qury to list only local accounts :
-filter "LocalAccount = True"

Answer (score 24):

*Update as an alternative to the excellent answer from 2010:*

You can now use the `Get-LocalGroupMember`, `Get-LocalGroup`, `Get-LocalUser` etc. from the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts) to get and map users and groups, available in PowerShell 5.1 and above.

Example:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-LocalGroupMember -name users

ObjectClass Name                             PrincipalSource 
----------- ----                             --------------- 
User        DESKTOP-R05QDNL\someUser1        Local           
User        DESKTOP-R05QDNL\someUser2        MicrosoftAccount
Group       NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE         Unknown
```

You could combine that with `Get-LocalUser`. Alias **`glu`** can also be used instead. Aliases exists for the majority of the new cmdlets.

In case some are wondering (I know you didn't ask about this)
Adding users could be for example done like so:

```
$description = "Netshare user"
$userName = "Test User"
$user = "test.user"
$pwd = "pwd123"

New-LocalUser $user -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force) -FullName $userName -Description $description
```

Comment: Thanks, @DavidMiguel - I've added this information to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Vish - I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to get an array with the local users and the groups they are member of:

```
Get-LocalUser | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $user = $_
        return [PSCustomObject]@{ 
            "User"   = $user.Name
            "Groups" = Get-LocalGroup | Where-Object {  $user.SID -in ($_ | Get-LocalGroupMember | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "SID") } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name"
        } 
    }
```

To get an array with the local groups and their members:

```
Get-LocalGroup | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $group = $_
        return [PSCustomObject]@{ 
            "Group"   = $group.Name
            "Members" = $group | Get-LocalGroupMember | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name"
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on mjswensen's answer, the command without the filter could take minutes, but the filtered command is almost instant.

**PowerShell - List local user accounts**

Fast way

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'" | select name, fullname
```

Slow way

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount |? {$_.localaccount -eq $true} | select name, fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :),

```
Get-LocalGroup | %{ $groups = "$(Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $_.Name | %{ $_.Name } | Out-String)"; Write-Output "$($_.Name)>`r`n$($groups)`r`n" }
```