# How to get the IADSUser native object from directory entry through powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, com, directoryentry

I wanted to get the groups of a local user account in windows.This can be done if we get the native object from the directory entry. This is achieved in the following way through APIs :

```
DirectoryEntry comp = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://computername");
DirectoryEntry de = comp.Children.Find("account19", "user");     
IADsUser NativeObject = (IADsUser)directoryentry.NativeObject;
```

But how to get the same thing through powershell script?

Comment: um.. maybe in powershell there's anther way to accomplish task on domain/local users using `[ADSI]`. Could you tell what's you final goal with `NativeObject`?

Comment: To get the groups of a user. One way is to get all the groups. Then their members and check if the user is a part of that group.But this is not efficient.

Comment: This should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548476/powershell-list-local-users-and-their-groups

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft .NET Framework types in the [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to obtain local group memberships. I wrote a simple PowerShell advanced function that will retrieve the group memberships for a local user account.

**Note**: Because we are using the [`GetGroups()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357862%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the [`UserPrincipal` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this code is very efficient. You do **not** need to get a list of all groups, and then iterate over them, as previously suggested in the comments.

```
function Get-LocalUserGroupMembership {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string] $Identity = $env:USERNAME
    )

    # Import the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement .NET library
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

    # Get a reference to the local machine's Security Account Manager (SAM)
    $PrincipalContext = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList ([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine);
    # Get a reference to a specific user principal, based on its account name
    $UserAccount = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($PrincipalContext, $Identity);
    if (!$UserAccount) {
        throw 'User account could not be found!';
    }

    # Call the GetGroups() method on the UserPrincipal object
    $GroupList = $UserAccount.GetGroups();

    # Output the list of groups
    Write-Output -InputObject $GroupList;
}

Get-LocalUserGroupMembership;
```

Comment: I tried the above script.I am getting the following exception : "Unhandled Exception: System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: User account could not be found!"