# Windows command to change the password for all users at once

Tags: windows

I was wondering if there's a way to change the password for all users at once on the command prompt. Maybe using net user? If not can you tell me a  way to get all the users from a batch file and then change all their passwords from there? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

step 1: Type `net user` in the command line and hit Enter. This will show down all the users of the computer.

step 2: `net user <username> *`

step 3: `net user nameoftheuser *`

You will be asked to enter a password for the user and then retype it.

**Note: This will only let you change one password at a time**

Comment: Yes. and unfortunately thats not what i'm looking for. I'm either looking for 1 command to change the password for all users at once, or a way to get all the users in a batch script and change the password with net user

Answer (score 1):

If the Powershell command prompt is available, [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/03/25/how-can-i-change-the-passwords-of-multiple-local-computer-accounts.aspx) will get you where you want to be.  Basically, use the technique described in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548476/powershell-list-local-users-and-their-groups) to build a list of users, and away you go.

If you don't have access to Powershell, then you can use WMI via VBScript to [fetch a list of users](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/827623f5-eb55-4035-8f57-25c4afb444cd), and/or [change passwords](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/vbscript_setpassword.htm).

Comment: This doesn't work either because it's for use on other computers, and I can't install anything

Comment: If the machines in question don't have Powershell, you can also use accomplish this using WMI via VBScript.  Most Windows machines come with support for VBScript (via cscript.exe/wscript.exe).  Updated answer with links to examples.

Comment: that's not an option either. I already am using batch. Thanks anyway

Comment: What is stopping you from invoking scripts from your batch files?

Comment: Yes. That would be a good option, but I don't think I need this anymore. Thanks for the help!