# Get membership of each local users on servers using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to get the local user list of a remote computer and what group they belong to using PowerShell script.

I tried: the below bit not able to use due to legacy version on many servers

```
Get-LocalUser
Get-LocalGroup
Get-LocalGroupMember
```

Also:

```
gwmi win32_UserAccount
gwmi win32_group
```

but it is very slow and pulling the information more than requirement which consumes time.

I would like the output formatted something like below:

```
User     Memberof
------   --------------------
a    Administrators
b    remote desktop users
c    Administrators,Backup Operators,users
6    remote desktop users,Backup Operators
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww5tP.png)

Comment: please provide a sample code you tried, a code that either need a fix or enhancement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [powershell - list local users and their groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548476/powershell-list-local-users-and-their-groups)

Comment: not duplicate and no forum has not finished with correct output:
--------

Comment: I have added codes in the attached image

Comment: Yeah, finally working for me...got some fine tune and get each object.