# Local users and their groups

Tags: powershell, adsi

I want to get a similar report as in the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548476/powershell-list-local-users-and-their-groups) for a bunch of computers retrieved from the AD.

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$($WKS.name)"
$adsi.Children | where { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' } | Foreach-Object {
    $groups = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object { $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) }
    $_ | Select-Object @{ n = 'UserName'; e = { $_.Name } }, @{ n = 'Groups'; e = { $groups -join ',' } } | | Export-Csv -Path "\\..\KontaLokalne.csv" -NoClobber -Append -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I want to get an additional information about each account listed - is the account enabled or not.

Additionally, I would like to send the output to the file in the format: **computer name**; account name; member of the groups.

Could You help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether a user account is enabled or not using ADSI, you will have to test if the `ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE` bit in the `.UserFlags` property is set or not.
To do this, you need to `bitwise and` the value of the UserFlags with the value of ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE (2):

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$($WKS.name)"
$result = $adsi.Children | Where-Object { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' } | ForEach-Object {
    $groups = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object { $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) }
    $_ | Select-Object @{Name = 'UserName'; Expression = { $_.Name } }, 
                       @{Name = 'Enabled';  Expression = { ($_.UserFlags.Value -band 2) -eq 0} },
                       @{Name = 'Groups';   Expression = { $groups -join ',' } }
}

# now you can export the resulting collection
# do you really want to use -Append here?
$result | Export-Csv -Path "\\..\KontaLokalne.csv" -NoClobber -Append -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

See [ADS_USER_FLAG_ENUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/ne-iads-ads_user_flag_enum)

Comment: Thank You @Theo. It works.
I want export in this place, because I add some more information to each position - computer name; it's location in AD OU, check's time. I want to import them to Excel for further analysis - filtration, sorting, etc. Each line provides complete information about source.